# Saving a media player video in the folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, video, media-player

Good Day sir, I have a project of a Media Player that can save a Video in a folder.
I made a button that can browse a files so i use the openfiledialog and after choosing a
video, the file path of a video is in the textbox that i made so this is my codes:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

My problem is the video that i selected is I want it to save in the folder that i named (savevideo). Can you help me with this?

Comment: Think you need the File.Copy method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're welcome. I've added a more detailed description as an answer for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
     if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
          this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
          File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName,
                    Path.Combine(savevideo, Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName)));
     }
 }
```

The Path.Combine bit builds you new file name to copy to, based on combining your 'savevideo' path, and the name of the original file.

Comment: Ahmmm sir @Baldrick what is FILE and PATH stands for?

Comment: They are classes in the System.IO namespace. To use the code as I've posted, you'll need to add 'using System.IO;' to the top of your code file.

Comment: Thank sir now it works but sir I still have an Error in the savevideo it says "The name 'savevideo' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: I got that from your post! :) You'll need to make sure you have a string variable called savevideo which contains the path of the folder you want to copy the file to. Best of luck.

Comment: ahhhh ok sir I forgot to put a string as "savevideo". thanks a lot sir. sorry for the inconvenience sir :)

Comment: No inconvenience! Always happy to help. :)